# XAMPP only responding to requets from localhost

Tags: apache-2.2, xampp

My XAMPP server is only responding to requets from the machine that's running it. I need it to repsond to requests from within a virtual PC as well as other machines on the network.

```
Listen 80
```

Is set in httpd.conf as apposed to Listen ipaddress:80, so I'm unsure why it won't serve pages to network users?

Edit: I should also mention that this worked with WAMP, so it's not to do with the hosts on the machines, they are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by adding port 80 as an exception in Windows Firewall on the machine running XAMPP.

However, I'm still rather confused as to why WAMP worked.